# Creating a global connection object across an executor in spark when pushing data to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, spark-streaming

In the [link](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#design-patterns-for-using-foreachrdd) it was suggested to create a connection pool that is available across multiple rdds in the spark streaming job.

```
rdd.foreachpartition( iter => {
val client = MongoClient(host,port)
val col = client.getDataBase("testDataBase").getCollection("testCollection")
```

// i am bascically inserting data in the iterator to the testcollection

})

However I was not able to figure out how to create a connection pool that returns a connection object to a mongodb collection. I was able to use foreachpartition to create a single connection for the whole partition. can someone please let me know how to create a connection object that available across the executor for reuse.

Comment: Hi @YuvalItzchakov  Here is what I did. I created a client object in foreachpartition which I used to push data to mongodb. can please clarify what do you want me to post exactly?

Comment: I want to see what code you have done towards an object pool.

Comment: hi @YuvalItzchakov. I posted the code which I am using. I couldn't figure out how to create a connection pool that is available across multiple partitions.

Answer (score 3):

The [MongoDB Spark Connector](http://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/) internally uses [broadcast variables](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables) to achieve this:

> Broadcast variables allow the programmer to keep a read-only variable cached on each machine rather than shipping a copy of it with tasks.

So you should be able to share the MongoClient and connection pool across tasks.

Comment: You probably have "inside" knowledge as you implemented this, but somehow I'm seeing large number of connections (more than 30 extra connections) opened to my mongo replica when spark job connecting to it is launched. Any reasons this could be happening?

Comment: The java driver internally will connect to members of the replica set as part of its high availability monitoring. There is an extensive spec regarding that process: https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/server-discovery-and-monitoring/server-discovery-and-monitoring-monitoring.rst 

Also there are connection pool settings for the Java driver that can be configured via the connection string. Some options relate to the connection pool:  http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.10/javadoc/com/mongodb/ConnectionString.html

Comment: That large number number of connections could have been caused by reading large amounts of data, but now I'm seeing some really weird behaviour - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55747576/why-doesnt-spark-mongo-connector-push-down-filters

Perhaps you have some knowledge of why Spark Mongo Connector behaves like this. Any tips appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Broadcast Variables store data in serialized state, and deserialize them before each task. Expensive initialization like establishing connections and authentication will have to be done again repeatedly for each task.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables

Answer (score -1):

Mongo dB spark connection doesn’t help in collecting exceptions. How do we do that. Also if we insert in batches , if one fails - it stops the remaining inserts. Mongo spark driver helps to insert multiple documents as well as you can set ordered = false so it even inserts the remaining documents even if there is some duplicates or some timeouts.

Comment: This does not appear to be an answer to the question.