# Why doesn't Spark Mongo connector push down filters?

Tags: database, mongodb, apache-spark

I have a large Mongo collection that I want to use in my Spark application, using Spark Mongo connector. The collection is quite large (>10 GB) and has daily data, with an index on `original_item.CreatedDate` field. Queries to select a couple of days in Mongo are extremely fast (under a second). However when I write the same query using dataframes, that filter is not pushed down to Mongo, resulting in extremely slow performance as Spark apparently fetches entire collection and does filtering itself.

Query looks the following way:

```
collection
      .filter("original_item.CreatedDate  > %s" % str(start_date_timestamp_ms)) \
      .filter("original_item.CreatedDate  < %s" % str(end_date_timestamp_ms)) \
      .select(...)
```

In physical plan I see:
`PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(original_item)]`

When I make a similar query with filtering on another field of that collection, mongo successfully pushes it down - `PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(original_item), IsNotNull(doc_type), EqualTo(doc_type,case)]`!

Could it be the case that `GreaterThan` filter pushing is not supported by Mongo Spark connector, or that there is a bug with it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the `GreaterThan` that's causing your issue, it's the fact that the filter is on a nested field.  Your filter on `doc_type` works because it's not nested.  This, apparently is an issue with the Catalyst engine in Spark, not the Mongo connector.  It affects predicate pushdowns in, e.g., Parquet as well.

See the following discussions in the Spark Jira for more details.

[Spark 19638](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19638)

[Spark 17636](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17636)