# How to extract only specific rows from mongodb using Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am extracting data from mongodb collection and writing it to bigquery table using Spark python code.

below is my code snippet:

```
df = spark.read\
    .format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource")\
    .option("uri","mongodb_url")\
    .option("database","db_name")\
    .option("collection", "collection_name")\
    .load()

df.write \
  .format("bigquery") \
  .mode("append")\
  .option("temporaryGcsBucket","gcs_bucket") \
  .option("createDisposition","CREATE_IF_NEEDED")\
  .save("bq_dataset_name.collection_name")
```

This will extract all the data from mongodb collection. but i want to extract only the documents which satisfied the condition(like where condition in sql query).

One way i found was to read whole data in dataframe and use filter on that dataframe like below:

```
df2 = df.filter(df['date'] < '12-03-2020 10:12:40')
```

But as my source mongo collection has 8-10 Gb of data, i cannot afford to read whole data everytime from mongo.

How can i use filtering while reading data from mongo using spark.read?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried checking if your whole data is being scanned even after applying filters?

Assuming you are using the [official connector](https://www.mongodb.com/products/spark-connector) with spark, filter/ predicate pushdown is supported.

> “Predicates pushdown” is an optimization from the connector and the
> Catalyst optimizer to automatically “push down” predicates to the data
> nodes. The goal is to maximize the amount of data filtered out on the
> data storage side before loading it into Spark’s node memory.

There are two kinds of predicates automatically pushed down by the connector to MongoDB:

- the `select` clause (projections) as a `$project`
- the `filter` clause content (`where`) as one or more `$match`

You can find the supporting code for this [over here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/mongodb/spark/sql/MongoRelationHelper.scala#L30).

Note:
There have been some issues regarding predicate pushdown on nested fields but this is a bug in spark itself and affects other sources as well. This has been fixed in Spark 3.x. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58036255/5718301) answer.